# In C#, what is the best way handle dependency inject a class which consumes multiple interfaces?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, conditional-statements, sftp, testability

I have a class which consumes Renci.SshNet's `SftpClient` which implements `BaseClient, ISftpClient`.

So, my constructor looks like:

```
    public CollendaSftpClient(
            CollendaCsvWriter collendaCsvWriter,
            CollendaSftpConfig collendaSftpConfig,
            ILogger<CollendaSftpClient> logger,
            ISftpClient sftpClient
        )
    {
        _collendaCsvWriter = collendaCsvWriter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collendaCsvWriter));
        _collendaSftpConfig = collendaSftpConfig ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collendaSftpConfig));
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _sftpClient = sftpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sftpClient));
    }
```

Annoyingling, `ISftpClient` does not include either the `Connect()` or `Disconnect()` methods, both of which are coming from `BaseClient` and included in `IBaseClient` (which `BaseClient` implements.

Thus, I have an upload method which looks like:

```
    private void Upload(MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        _logger.InterpolatedInformation($"Attempting to upload to {_collendaSftpConfig.Host:SftpHost}");
        try
        {
            SftpClient? sftpClient = _sftpClient as SftpClient;
            if (sftpClient != default)
            {
                sftpClient.Connect();
            }

            string filePath = _collendaSftpConfig?.FilePath
                ?.InsertTimestamp()
                ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("CollendaSftpConfig configuration is missing FilePath.");

            // Renci.SshNet's Sftp Client seems to have some async support, but it seems much more complicated to consume.
            // There is no clear benefit to using it at this time.
            _sftpClient.UploadFile(memoryStream, filePath);
            if (sftpClient != default)
            {
                sftpClient.Disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CollendaSftpException sftpException = new($"Failed to upload to {_collendaSftpConfig.Host:SftpHost}", ex);
            _logger.InterpolatedError(sftpException, $"Upload failure: {ex.Message:ErrorMessage}");
            throw sftpException;
        }
    }
```

Needing to check whether I've injected an instance of something else looks ugly and not especially testable...  Nor does it seem like a great idea to add it to my services and inject it twice.

Short of asking Renci to fix their interace, what is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: a.) check in the constructor that the injected thing is also a Baseclient so it fails early in case. or b.) add another layer of abstraction (a factory or connection pool) that gets injected instead and delivers a already connected ISftpClient so the user(the shown class) does no need to know the extra stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I suggest a small redesign of your application? Prefer to let application code depend only on application-specific abstractions, conforming to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

In your case `CollendaSftpClient` depends on the third-party `ISftpClient` abstraction and `SftpClient` class. These types are not designed specifically for your application, which causes testability issues, as you already noticed.

Instead, hide `SftpClient` behind an application-specific abstraction, for instance:

```cs
public interface IFileUploader
{
    void Upload(string path, MemoryStream data);
}
```

This abstraction contains solely an `Upload` method. It lacks `Connect` and `Disconnect` methods, because the consumers of `IFileUpload` will (or should) not be concerned in making and breaking the connection. This can be done in the background, by the implemention of `IFileUploader` that [adapts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to `SftpClient`. For instance:

```cs
public sealed class SftpClientFileUploaderAdapter : IFileUploader
{
    public SftpClientFileUploaderAdapter(SftpClient sftpClient) ...
    
    public void Upload(string path, MemoryStream data)
    {
        _sftpClient.Connect();
        
        try
        {
            _sftpClient.UploadFile(data, filePath);
        }
        finally
        {
            sftpClient.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

This adapter depends directly on the `SftpClient` class—not the interface. It is allowed to do this, because this adapter will be part of your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) or [Anti-Corruption Layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/anti-corruption-layer) (depending on which terminology you follow). This allows it to connect and disconnect.

Note that this class lacks logging. That's because logging is a [cross-cutting concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) and cross-cutting concerns are best placed in their own class. For instance, you can create this [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for `IFileUploader`:

```cs
public sealed class LoggingFileUploader : IFileUploader
{
    public LoggingFileUploader(
        CollendaSftpConfig collendaSftpConfig,
        ILogger logger,
        IFileUploader decoratee) ...
    
    public void Upload(string path, MemoryStream data)
    {
        _logger.InterpolatedInformation(
            $"Attempting to upload to {_collendaSftpConfig.Host:SftpHost}");
        
        try
        {
            _decoratee.Upload(path, data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CollendaSftpException sftpException = new(
                $"Failed to upload to {_collendaSftpConfig.Host:SftpHost}", ex);
            _logger.InterpolatedError(sftpException,
                $"Upload failure: {ex.Message:ErrorMessage}");
            throw;
        }        
    }
}
```

This Decorator implements `IFileUploader` while it also wraps and uses an `IFileUploader` itself. This allows to 'extend' the behavior of the `SftpClientFileUploaderAdapter` while using [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Note that this piece of catching and logging of exceptions would raise a red flag when I do a code review over such piece of code. In general, when you let the exception bubble up the call stack (using the `throw` keyword) there's no need to log that exception in the `catch` block. Instead, you typically let the exception bubble up and log the exception at the top of the call stack.

In this case I, therefore, find it more reasonable to add more details to the exception message (as you are doing) and simply throw that new message. For instance:

```cs
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new CollendaSftpException(
        $"Failed to upload to {_collendaSftpConfig.Host:SftpHost}", ex);
}
```

This leaves the following code in the `CollendaSftpClient` class:

```cs
public CollendaSftpClient(
    CollendaSftpConfig collendaSftpConfig,
    IFileUploader fileUploader) ...

private void Upload(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    string filePath = _collendaSftpConfig?.FilePath?.InsertTimestamp();
    
    if (filePath is null) throw new InvalidOperationException(
        "CollendaSftpConfig configuration is missing FilePath.");

    _fileUploader.UploadFile(filePath, memoryStream);
}
```

Inside your Composition Root, you can now construct this new object structure as follows:

```cs
var config = new CollendaSftpConfig();
var ftpClient = new SftpClient { ... };
new CollendaSftpClient(
    config,
    new LoggingFileUploader(
        config,
        new Logger<LoggingFileUploader>(),
        new SftpClientFileUploaderAdapter(ftpClient)));
```

Or in case you're using MS.DI as your DI Container:

```cs
services.AddTransient<CollendaSftpClient>();
services.AddTransient<IFileUploader>(sp =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<LoggingFileUploader>(sp,
        sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<LoggingFileUploader>>(),
        ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<SftpClientFileUploaderAdapter>(sp)));
```

Please note that the suggestions above are written with just the information extracted from your question, with no knowledge about your application and domain. Please adapt this code to fit your application or use the ideas presented to improve your application design. Chances are slim that these code samples are the best-fit your application.

Comment: Awesome response!  I'll need to do some research to better understand "Composition Root" and "Anti-corruption Layer", but this makes a LOT of sense and actually very well targeted my application (which is using MS.DI).   (I would accept the answer right away, but I want to test and see if I get any other answers first.)